# Copper Blackening Biproducts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Apologies in advance for what is likely an incredibly basic question.

I am trying to form CuO from a Cu thin film using a bath of 1l DI water, 50g NaOH, 50g NaClO2.  I am wondering what the biproducts will be?

The reaction is described in this paper.  https://pubs.aip.org/aip/rsi/article/87/5/053119/982365/In-vacuum-scattered-light-reduction-with-black